# How do I get a resource using Class, ClassLoader, and URL

Tags: java, class, jsf, classloader, getresource

I am writing a simple JSF application and am trying to get a resource (database.properties file) using `Class`, `ClassLoader`, and `URL` that is not working. url is null and I don't know why.  I have done a lot of research but without success.

### Code:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("<packagename>.SimpleDataSource");
ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
URL url = cLoader.getResource(fileName); // fileName = "database.properties"  w/o the double quote
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(url.getFile());
```

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.in/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html Scroll down to the section `Properties file loader`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment Sandeep, it was helpful.  I found out that my properties file was in the wrong place.  I then moved it inside my src folder under the java resources folder and now my properties file gets loaded in.  I have a new problem now but will start a new thread if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a URL you can get an `InputStream` from it using `url.openStream()`, or you can simply use `cLoader.getResourceAsStream(...)` in the first place.  Your current approach of

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(url.getFile());
```

will work on some platforms but not all, and only when your application is running from a directory on disk.  It will fail if your classes and resources are packed up into a JAR, but if you use `getResourceAsStream` it will work from a JAR as well as an unpacked directory.